# Integrating Vuforia with Unity for Real Object Tracking in VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, vuforia, htc-vive

I'm working on a Unity project (version 2020.3.8f1) that involves a 3D environment using the SteamVR package for HTC VIVE interaction. Additionally, I'm using the Leap Motion controller to enable user interaction with virtual objects in the scene.

Now, I want to take it a step further and incorporate real-world objects that are tracked within the virtual environment, with their virtual representations visible. For this purpose, I've decided to explore Vuforia.

My goal is to use Vuforia to detect real-world objects captured by the camera (and, if necessary, which type of camera should I use?). Once detected, I want to track these objects as they move and display their virtual representations within the virtual environment I've developed.

I'm a bit uncertain about the steps involved and whether this is achievable. Could someone please guide me on how to approach this integration? Any tips, resources, or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at these tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yW3iLmn7IG8 ?

Comment: thank you for this tutorial but the video doesn't answer to my question. This is a different thing!

Comment: If your goal is to use the Vive with Vuforia then please note that it is not a supported platform so it definitely does not work out of the box.